# Keeping selected item in select box after submit

Tags: php, html

I would like to keep the selected year after the system's response. I would also like to improve the code. thanks to all

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp  method="post"> 


<select name="YEAR7" size="1">
<option value="2014">2014</option> <option value="2015">2015</option> 
<option value="2014">2014</option> <option value="2013">2013</option> 
<option value="2012">2012</option> <option value="2011">2011</option>  
</select>
<input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe submit the form in an iframe or the better answer would be to use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Add the selected attribute to the right values.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=category&amp;layout=blog&amp"  method="post">
    <select name="YEAR7" size="1">
        <option value="2015" <?php echo trim($_POST['YEAR7']) == '2015' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>2015</option>
        <option value="2014" <?php echo trim($_POST['YEAR7']) == '2014' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>2014</option>
        <option value="2013" <?php echo trim($_POST['YEAR7']) == '2013' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>2013</option>
        <option value="2012" <?php echo trim($_POST['YEAR7']) == '2012' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>2012</option>
        <option value="2011" <?php echo trim($_POST['YEAR7']) == '2011' ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?>>2011</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```