# Set option value from php variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<form method="post" id="employee" action="change.php">
<select id="employeename" name="employeename" onchange="this.form.submit()">
 <?php 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>    
</select>
</form>
```

The form will be submitted when select value is changed,

Once the form is submitted, it will redirect to the same page. How do I set the selected option value with the one I just selected?

Comment: you means you want to show option value selected after loading the page.

Comment: Yes, thats what I want.

Comment: if($_POST['employeename']==$row['name']){     echo "<option value='".$row['name']." selected'>".$row['name']."</option>";
}else{    echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
} add this code in loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep values selected after form submission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246227/keep-values-selected-after-form-submission)

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327008/keeping-selected-item-in-select-box-after-submit>

Comment: @BehradKhodayar: it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form, especially the `<select>` dropdown list in the following way,

```
<form method="post" id="employee" action="change.php">
    <select id="employeename" name="employeename" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <?php 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $output = "<option value='".$row['name']."'";
                if($_POST['employeename'] == $row['name']){
                    $output .= " selected='selected'";
                }
                $output .= ">".$row['name']."</option>";
                echo $output;
            }
        ?>    
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form method="post" id="employee" action="change.php">
    <select id="employeename" name="employeename" onchange="this.form.submit()">
     <?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
   if($_POST['employeename']==$row['name'])
        echo "<option value='".$row['name']."' selected>".$row['name']."</option>";
else 
   echo "<option value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>";
    }
    ?>    
    </select>
    </form>
```

just marked as selected if you find selected key in available list.